# ClosedXml Range Error

Tags: c#, excel, closedxml

I am using ClosedXml and I am getting the following error when trying create 
a range of headers from a range table.

> The cells A13 and P13 are outside the range
>   ''SalesOrderHeaderId_1'!A7:P8'.

Here is the C# Code I am using to try and create the range:

```
var sohRngTable = ws.Range("A7:P8");
var sohRngHeaders = sohRngTable.Range("A7:P7");
```

It fails on the second line trying to create sohRngHeaders, it acts like there is some default size for a worksheet but I am not sure and I can't figure out how to change it or get past this error.

Answer (score 1):

The address is relative to the parent range, so you have to use:

```
var sohRngHeaders = sohRngTable.Range("A1:P1");
```

This is explained in the comments in the [documentation you also linked to](https://github.com/closedxml/closedxml/wiki/Showcase) in your [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43263594/closedxml-range-error#comment73599885_43264237) to another answer:

```
// From another range
var rngDates = rngTable.Range("D3:D5");   // The address is relative to rngTable (NOT the worksheet)
var rngNumbers = rngTable.Range("E3:E5"); // The address is relative to rngTable (NOT the worksheet)

                                             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

Comment: We could use your good knowledge of ClosedXML in the project. If you have time, please help answer issues on the GitHub page too.